# Getting null on URL (Vaadin)

Tags: vaadin

I'm getting a null on my URL after I logged-in in google chrome

http://localhost:8080/app/null

but I don't have a problem when using Firefox or Safari

```
@PermitAll
@Route("")
public class MainLayout extends AppLayout {
}
```

[image]

I just added my login code. I'm implementing Vaadin Security based on the documentation. https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/security/enabling-security

```
@Route("login")
@RouteAlias(value = "login")
@PageTitle("Login | SAVE")
public class LoginView extends VerticalLayout implements BeforeEnterObserver {

private final LoginForm login = new LoginForm();

public LoginView() {
    addClassName("login-view");
    setSizeFull();
    setAlignItems(Alignment.CENTER);
    setJustifyContentMode(JustifyContentMode.CENTER);

    login.setAction("login");

    add(new H1("Society Agri-Venture Enterprise"), login);

}

@Override
public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent beforeEnterEvent) {
    // inform the user about an authentication error
    if(beforeEnterEvent.getLocation()
            .getQueryParameters()
            .getParameters()
            .containsKey("error")) {
        login.setError(true);
    }
}

}
```

Security Configuration class

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends VaadinWebSecurity {

@Autowired
private AccountService accountService;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // Delegating the responsibility of general configurations
    // of http security to the super class. It's configuring
    // the followings: Vaadin's CSRF protection by ignoring
    // framework's internal requests, default request cache,
    // ignoring public views annotated with @AnonymousAllowed,
    // restricting access to other views/endpoints, and enabling
    // ViewAccessChecker authorization.
    // You can add any possible extra configurations of your own
    // here (the following is just an example):

    // http.rememberMe().alwaysRemember(false);

    // Configure your static resources with public access before calling
    // super.configure(HttpSecurity) as it adds final anyRequest matcher
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/public/**")
            .permitAll();

    super.configure(http);

    // This is important to register your login view to the
    // view access checker mechanism:
    setLoginView(http, LoginView.class);
}

@Bean
PasswordEncoder bcryptPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    // Customize your WebSecurity configuration.
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/images/**")
            .antMatchers("/VAADIN/**");
    super.configure(web);
}

protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws  Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
}

@Bean
DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

    daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(bcryptPasswordEncoder());

 daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(this.accountService);
    return daoAuthenticationProvider;
}

}
```

Security Service class

```
@Component
public class SecurityService {

private static final String LOGOUT_SUCCESS_URL = "/app";

public UserDetails getAuthenticatedUser() {
    SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    Object principal = context.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
        return (UserDetails) principal;
    }
    // Anonymous or no authentication.
    return null;
}

public void logout() {
    UI.getCurrent().getPage().setLocation(LOGOUT_SUCCESS_URL);
    SecurityContextLogoutHandler logoutHandler = new SecurityContextLogoutHandler();
    logoutHandler.logout(
            VaadinServletRequest.getCurrent().getHttpServletRequest(), null,
            null);
}

}
```

Comment: The problem is not in your MainLayout, it's likely in your login / authentication code. You should add that to the question

Comment: Hi @ollitietavainen, I added my login code. I just followed the authentication code based on the documentation using Vaadin Security.

Comment: Your Route and RouteAlias have the same value, that does not make sense.

Comment: Where does "app" come from? Is this the context-path you deployed the application under? I'd find that odd, that the error comes from your container and not the vaadin application telling you existing routes (unless of course, this is a production deployment)

Comment: @garagumo that login view isn't the part that handles the authentication, that's just the visual side. You probably have a security configuration class?

Comment: @TatuLund, sorry about the RouteAlias, it was supposed to be commented out.

Comment: @cfrick, the "app" comes from the application properties, server.servlet.context-path=/app 

I'm using nginx for my web server and implement reverse proxy with my Vaadin App

Comment: @ollitietavainen, I edited my post and added my security configuration class. I just copied it from Vaadin documentation.

Comment: The security configuration looks ok, but it could be something with your proxy setup. Does the issue also occur if you run the application without a proxy?

Comment: @ollitietavainen, the app is ok using mozilla and safari. it just wont work with chrome.

Comment: Yes, but what about without the proxy? Does the issue with Chrome occur then?

Comment: @ollitietavainen, yes.. still there. I only use proxy in prod

Comment: It could be a bug, then. My hunch is that it's something to do with the servlet context path configuration, but that's just a guess. I recommend creating a minimal reproducible example and submitting a bug ticket to https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/new/choose

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the problem. The culprit was really my google chrome. I just have to reset it to default settings.